# How can I get aligned memory from the CMA (Contiguous Memory Allocator) on Linux?

Tags: memory-management, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, allocation, dma

I am trying to get a gigabyte-aligned CMA region on a x86 machine.
I've specified a 2G CMA region to start at a gigabyte-aligned address (0x100000000), but when I do an allocation with dma_alloc_coherent(), the physical address I get is the 0x100100000, which is not aligned. Do you have any idea why this is happening and how can I get an aligned address? (eg. 0x100000000, or 0x1400000000 etc.) I am on x86, and cannot use device tree.
Many thanks

Comment: https://www.programmersought.com/article/35407581068/

Comment: I think `dma_pool_create` and `dma_pool_alloc` are the required functions.

Comment: Hi @IanAbbott , I've used these 2 functions like this: pool = dma_pool_create("CMA", &pdev->dev, GIGABYTE, 0x40000000, 0x40000000); But again, the region that is returned with kbuff = dma_pool_alloc(pool, GFP_KERNEL, &dma_handle); starts at 0x100200000 .. Is this the expected behaviour or am I missing something with regards to alignment?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work but it seems `dma_pool_create` and `dma_pool_alloc` would be very wasteful anyway in this case because the allocation size gets rounded up to a multiple of the alignment size.

Comment: @IanAbbott DMA poll is usually for **descriptors**, while DMA coherent memory, such as wanted here, is for raw buffers.

Comment: I suppose there is always the option of allocating a load of buffers and putting them in a temporary list until a suitably aligned buffer has been allocated, and then freeing the unneeded buffers. The list would need to store both the virtual address and the DMA handle of each buffer.

Comment: ... It would end up being quite a long temporary list on average though when searching for a 1 megabyte buffer aligned on a gigabyte boundary!